# How to connect my Android app to an online mysql database?

Tags: android, mysql, wamp

This is my first post on StackOverflow. So I apologize if such a post exists already.

I have created a Movie Database using WAMP MySQL that is currently saved on my computer HDD. I'm currently working on an Android app that can manipulate my database (update tables, delete rows, fetch information) & will also show which DVDs contain which movies (I have over 1TB of movies stored in DVDs).

So how do I go about it? Do I create a completely new database online using those free Database hosting sites available or is there a way I can connect my android app to my WAMP Database server & access it from anywhere I want with the help of Internet?

Comment: it most likely will not work outside of your home (and you probably don't want it to, unless you have a full understanding of how to run a server).  On top of that you'll have bandwidth issues as well.  Also note that you won't find any "free" servers online that will allow anywhere near a TB of storage. Typically they might provide 2GB, and if you are watching movies, bandwidth would also become an issue, where they'd either shut you down or start charging you.

Comment: I won't upload any movies on my DB. My database will only contain information about the movies like genre, releasing year, DVD no. in which the movie is stored etc. And my app should work like how IMDB works. You type a movie name & it shows you info. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You could host this on a remote server.  Again, I wouldn't try turning your home server into something public unless you really know what you are doing (and your service provider allows it)

Comment: Thank you very much @nomistic